# What word will literally convey '52 times a year'?

Tags: single-word-requests

If I do something twice a year, it's semi-annual. But what if I do something 52 times a year?

I have to send a reminder to my team about our weekly meeting (update their minutes, time, projects, etc). Traditionally, we all add some personal flavor to it. I'm looking to spice it up by referring to the meeting as a [word-meaning-split-into-52]annual meeting.

Additional commentary:

It has been suggested that 'duoquinquagensimannual' may be the proper term. However a search on Google has provided yields only this post, leaving me to believe there may be a more appropriate term.

Additionally, I sent the reminder this morning using the phrase 'Hebdomadal' as suggested. It does accurately convey what the meeting is, while still making it less boring than 'weekly'. (Pff, how boring is weekly?) However, despite its usefulness at solving my business concern, it fails to meet the specific criteria set forth by the request. So it will indeed be useful for anyone else potentially seeking the same phrase I seek, we're unfortunately left with an unanswered question.

Comment: semi-fortnightly

Comment: @JeffSahol Oh I do like that. It also doesn't cause the problem of there being 52.14 (or 52.28) weeks a year!

Comment: *centiannually*, 100 times a year; so *bi-centiannually*, 50 times a year.  So, take two weekly meeting off for holidays...

Answer (score 27):

*Hebdomadal* is the word you want.

> weekly (used especially of organizations that meet weekly)
> [[Oxford Languages]](https://www.google.com/search?q=hebdomadal%20define)

Comment: Excellent! http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hebdomadal : From _hebdomas_ ("week")

Comment: While this isn't the word I was looking for, it is the word I plan to use. Out of curiousity, how would one construct the word meaning '52 times a year'? I'm sure it's just the concatenation of a prefix and annual, but what would the prefix be?

Comment: You could try ‘duoquinquagensimannual’!

Answer (score 8):

Previously-mentioned *[hebdomadal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hebdomadal)* ("Weekly, occurring once a week") seems a good choice for referring to the meeting frequency, but for reports and  minutes brought to the meeting you might refer to *heptameric reports*, after the noun
*[heptameron](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/heptameron)* ("A literary work whose action covers a period of seven days").

Answer (score 2):

But every fourth year, at least, it'll be 53 times, not 52, so what you really need seems to be a word that means "every seven days".

And, as Barrie points out, that's ***Hebdomadal*** /hɛb'dɔmədəl/.

This is simply Latin for 'weekly', which is itself from the Greek *hebdomas*, from *hepta*, the number 'seven'. Compare Latin *septem*, 'seven', and [other PIE numerals](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/PIENumerals.pdf).

Comment: Pronounce it roughly as *abdominal*, and you're on the right track.

Comment: Exercise for the student: Write a poem in which you rhyme hebdomadal with abdominal.